# Slow nfs4 performance and "nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length."

Tags: nfs

I have my imac macos12.5.1 connected over gigabit ethernet to my debian fileserver.

When transferring a single large file of about 10GB via nfs4, throughput is something like 60MB/s but probably even less as it fluctuates. Transferring many small files is basically useless...

The same transfer of a single large file via ssh is about 120MB/s which is what I would expect.

imac nfs `/etc/nfs.conf` config is `nfs.client.mount.options = vers=4,inet,nfc` with mount command: `sudo mount -o vers=4,resvport,noatime -t nfs 10.0.0.2:/jake /Volumes/jake`

debian config is:

```
/srv/nfs4               10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,fsid=0)
/srv/nfs4/jake      10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)
```

In imac console there are many repeats of this error: `nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.` though I wish there was a way to get more verbose logging on the mac?

imac:

```
default 12:25:38.136101+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xd
default 12:25:38.136116+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xe
default 12:25:38.136400+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:38.136406+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xe
default 12:25:39.150085+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xe
default 12:25:39.150096+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xf
default 12:25:39.150372+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:39.150376+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xf
default 12:25:39.486855+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xf
default 12:25:39.486865+0200    kernel  nfs recovery throttled for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0xf
default 12:25:40.486901+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x10
default 12:25:40.488338+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:40.489782+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:40.489788+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x10
default 12:25:40.700112+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x10
default 12:25:41.489896+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x11
default 12:25:41.491097+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 0 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:41.492681+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:41.492686+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x11
default 12:25:41.584213+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x11
default 12:25:41.584225+0200    kernel  nfs recovery throttled for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x11
default 12:25:42.584335+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x12
default 12:25:42.585711+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 0 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:42.587117+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:42.587125+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x12
default 12:25:44.484054+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x12
default 12:25:44.484064+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x13
default 12:25:44.485599+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:44.487035+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:44.487041+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x13
default 12:25:44.584136+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x13
default 12:25:44.584148+0200    kernel  nfs recovery throttled for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x13
default 12:25:45.584211+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x14
default 12:25:45.585335+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 0 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:45.586734+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:45.586740+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x14
default 12:25:45.739166+0200    kernel  nfs_mount_state_in_use_end: error 10025, initiating recovery for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x14
default 12:25:45.739187+0200    kernel  nfs recovery throttled for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x14
default 12:25:46.739695+0200    kernel  nfs recovery started for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x15
default 12:25:46.740104+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 0 <private> 0x0 ._iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:46.740462+0200    kernel  nfs_recover: 10033, need reopen for 501 <private> 0x4 iTunes_Old.zip
default 12:25:46.740468+0200    kernel  nfs recovery completed for 10.0.0.2:/jake, 0x15
nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.
nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.
nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.
nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.
nfs_buf_write_rpc: Got request with zero length.
...
```

On the server, I have turned on all logging with `rpcdebug -m nfsd -s all`, but it looks pretty normal there:

```
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.921851] NFSD: nfsd4_locku: start=0 length=-1
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.921966] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.921972] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.921975] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578066)
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.922095] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.922099] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000f3b51988
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.922210] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980736.922212] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980737.036966] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980737.070435] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980737.070444] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:45 jake kernel: [10980737.070447] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:46 jake kernel: [10980738.077305] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:47 jake kernel: [10980738.625893] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:47 jake kernel: [10980738.625902] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:47 jake kernel: [10980738.625905] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:47 jake kernel: [10980738.627803] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:47 jake kernel: [10980738.627807] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:48 jake kernel: [10980739.538334] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:48 jake kernel: [10980739.538342] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:48 jake kernel: [10980739.538345] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:48 jake kernel: [10980739.539802] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:48 jake kernel: [10980739.539806] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:50 jake kernel: [10980741.378829] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:50 jake kernel: [10980741.378838] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:50 jake kernel: [10980741.378841] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:50 jake kernel: [10980741.380232] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:50 jake kernel: [10980741.380236] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:51 jake kernel: [10980742.543108] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:52 jake kernel: [10980743.440074] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:52 jake kernel: [10980743.440083] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:52 jake kernel: [10980743.440086] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:52 jake kernel: [10980743.441429] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:52 jake kernel: [10980743.441432] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980744.433298] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980745.042826] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980745.042835] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980745.042838] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980745.044459] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:53 jake kernel: [10980745.044462] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:54 jake kernel: [10980745.888155] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:54 jake kernel: [10980745.888165] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:54 jake kernel: [10980745.888168] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:54 jake kernel: [10980745.889786] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:54 jake kernel: [10980745.889789] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:55 jake kernel: [10980746.885564] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:55 jake kernel: [10980746.885573] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:55 jake kernel: [10980746.885576] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:55 jake kernel: [10980746.887166] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:55 jake kernel: [10980746.887169] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:56 jake kernel: [10980747.994541] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:56 jake kernel: [10980747.994549] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:56 jake kernel: [10980747.994552] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:56 jake kernel: [10980747.996160] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:57 jake kernel: [10980748.824736] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:57 jake kernel: [10980748.826163] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:25:57 jake kernel: [10980748.826166] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:58 jake kernel: [10980749.739235] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:25:59 jake kernel: [10980750.648142] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:25:59 jake kernel: [10980750.648151] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:25:59 jake kernel: [10980750.648154] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:25:59 jake kernel: [10980750.649758] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:26:00 jake kernel: [10980751.504257] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980752.326509] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980752.326518] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980752.326521] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578067)
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980752.328123] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980752.328126] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980753.011290] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:26:01 jake kernel: [10980753.011299] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:26:02 jake kernel: [10980754.125527] NFSD: nfsd4_open filename ._iTunes_Old.zip op_openowner 0000000000000000
Aug 20 12:26:02 jake kernel: [10980754.125536] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:26:02 jake kernel: [10980754.127558] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:26:03 jake kernel: [10980755.035125] nfsd: nfsd_lookup(fh 32: 01060001 43e0e405 0c844900 00000000 00000000 cd36000a, ._iTunes_Old.zip)
Aug 20 12:26:03 jake kernel: [10980755.036554] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file ._iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:27:12 jake kernel: [10980824.256483] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/iTunes_Old.zip, ino=578066)
Aug 20 12:27:12 jake kernel: [10980824.257475] NFSD: nfsd4_close on file iTunes_Old.zip
Aug 20 12:27:12 jake kernel: [10980824.257480] NFSD: move_to_close_lru nfs4_openowner 00000000ccb5ab4a
Aug 20 12:27:12 jake kernel: [10980824.257880] nfsd: fh_compose(exp 00:33/4 test/._iTunes_Old.zip, ino=0)
```

If I do nfsstat mid-transfer I get this:

```
nfsstat
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badfmt     badauth    badclnt
19729045   0          0          0          0

Server nfs v4:
null             compound
13023     0%     19716448 99%

Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused       op1-unused       op2-future       access           close
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     3724434   7%     60078     0%
commit           create           delegpurge       delegreturn      getattr
23014     0%     210       0%     0         0%     37471     0%     7738440  16%
getfh            link             lock             lockt            locku
150218    0%     0         0%     45477     0%     10        0%     40472     0%
lookup           lookup_root      nverify          open             openattr
1339991   2%     0         0%     0         0%     3831292   8%     0         0%
open_conf        open_dgrd        putfh            putpubfh         putrootfh
286       0%     6         0%     19633355 41%     0         0%     32        0%
read             readdir          readlink         remove           rename
8281709  17%     163145    0%     72        0%     38622     0%     46        0%
renew            restorefh        savefh           secinfo          setattr
59667     0%     45495     0%     496788    1%     2407      0%     4348      0%
setcltid         setcltidconf     verify           write            rellockowner
13023     0%     13025     0%     0         0%     1477285   3%     0         0%
bc_ctl           bind_conn        exchange_id      create_ses       destroy_ses
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
free_stateid     getdirdeleg      getdevinfo       getdevlist       layoutcommit
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
layoutget        layoutreturn     secinfononam     sequence         set_ssv
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
test_stateid     want_deleg       destroy_clid     reclaim_comp     allocate
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
copy             copy_notify      deallocate       ioadvise         layouterror
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
layoutstats      offloadcancel    offloadstatus    readplus         seek
0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%     0         0%
write_same
0         0%
```